# Ubuntu Reset System loop, Boot-Loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 computer and tried to set up dual boot, but after doing so, the message "Reset Systems" appeared in the top left corner of the screen and the computer began to restart repeatedly. After seeing this, I gave up on dual boot and reinstalled Ubuntu by selecting the "Erase disk" option (i.e. formatting the disk), but I still got the same error. The strange thing is that I can boot Ubuntu successfully by accessing the boot menu by pressing the F12 key before the computer starts up. However, when I enter the BIOS settings and check the boot priority order, Ubuntu does not appear. I'm tired of doing this manually every time. I've tried many things and watched many videos, but I haven't been able to fix the problem. I tried using Boot Repair, but no recommended repairs were shown. I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Is this an Acer or what brand/model system? Acer requires you to set "trust" in UEFI settings. Other brands may also need UEFI settings changes. Or did you not install in UEFI mode & system is set for UEFI boot? Post the link to the Summary report Boot-Repair gives.